# R dplyr count observations within groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with yes/no values for different days and hours.  For each day, I want to get a total number of hours where I have data, as well as the total number of hours where there is a value of Y.

```
df <- data.frame(day = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4),
                 hour = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4,1),
                 YN = c("Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","N"))

df %>% 
  group_by(day) %>%
  summarise(tot.hour = n(),
            totY = WHAT DO I PUT HERE?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using boolean then add it up

```
df %>% 
    group_by(day) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(tot.hour = n(),
              totY = sum(YN=='Y'))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
    day tot.hour  totY
  <dbl>    <int> <int>
1     1        3     3
2     2        2     2
3     3        4     1
4     4        1     0
```